# Value equals to match_parent or fill_parent in dimens.xml?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-resources, dimension

Based on [here on XML Attributes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html) section I specify following in my `dimens.xml`:

```
<dimen name="match_parent">-1dp</dimen>
<dimen name="main_left_menu_user_account_width">@dimen/match_parent</dimen>
<dimen name="main_left_menu_user_account_height">@dimen/match_parent</dimen>
```

Then I use the both dimensions in my layout:

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/userAccountImage"
    android:background="@drawable/user_account"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/main_left_menu_user_account_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/main_left_menu_user_account_height" />
```

Then, when I preview to `Graphical Layout`, it complains:

> You must supply a layout_width attribute.
>
> You must supply a layout_height attribute.

Actually can I define a value equals to match_parent in `dimens.xml`?

**Update:**

I also tried this but the preview still complains:

```
<dimen name="main_left_menu_user_account_width">-1dp</dimen>
<dimen name="main_left_menu_user_account_height">-1dp</dimen>
```

I successfully use `wrap_content` (the `Graphical Layout` doesn't complain at all):

```
<dimen name="wrap_content">-2dp</dimen>

<dimen name="main_right_menu_width">@dimen/wrap_content</dimen>
<dimen name="main_right_menu_height">@dimen/wrap_content</dimen>
```

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://mytechsolutions.blogspot.com.es/2011/04/unable-to-resolve-dimension-value.html)? An option could be using styles.

Comment: @AlexBcn yeah, but still the same. I think the SDK doesn't like with -1dp value, please see my edited post.

Comment: How does it "complain"?  Are you using the latest Eclipse plugin?  I seem to be able to use -1dp without issue in the layout preview.

Comment: Really? My SDK is 21.1 and platform-tools 16.0.1.. How about yours?

Comment: I'm using your approach with -1dp and -2dp and it works on actual devices (Nexus10), thanks.

Comment: Use a style instead of dimen

Answer (score 56):

Use this, it works for me

```
<dimen name="custom_wrap_content">-2px</dimen>  
<dimen name="horizontal_border_height">@dimen /custom_wrap_content</dimen>

<dimen name="custom_match_parent">-1px</dimen>  
<dimen name="vertical_border_height">@dimen /custom_match_parent</dimen>
```

And the Reason why `match_parent` doesn't run. **You cannot supply a build in keyword like `match_parent`**

**Edit:** Use `px` instead of `dp` as suggested by Jarett Millard in the comments.

Comment: Android Studio 0.5.3, SDK Tools 22.6.1 don't like the use of an integer as a dimen value :(

Comment: Try -1dp and -2dp. They are AS friendly :)

Comment: Use `-1px` and `-2px` instead of `dp`. The `px` values will not scale based on the device's screen density.

Comment: @Ambran On Android O you can use 0dp in most cases to make it "match constraint" (if you're using Constraint Layout). But I still have no idea how to solve the "wrap_content" problem.

Comment: In my case the -1px value resets the View's margins, So if your view needs some margins use [Fonix's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39523353/9317258). It works fine.

Answer (score 43):

First create attribs.xml:

```
<resources>
    <item name="match_parent" type="dimen">-1</item>
    <item name="wrap_content" type="dimen">-2</item>
</resources>
```

Second use your dimens:

```
   <dimen name="account_width">@dimen/match_parent</dimen>
   <dimen name="account_height">@dimen/wrap_content</dimen>
```

Comment: This gives me a Resources$NotFoundException.. :(

Comment: `-1px` and `-2px` respectively. first, not `dp` but `px` because of scaling, second, without dimension classification emulator api 25 failing in runtime for me with error `layout_width not specified` or something like that

Comment: Seems to work so far :) I've used `custom_match_parent` and `custom_wrap_content` as names to not confuse people.

Answer (score 27):

Depending on why you want to define `match_parent` in a @dimen, this use case could help you:

Instead of defining the width and height in dimen.xml, you can define it as a style in the styles.xml

I use

```
//res/values/styles.xml
<style name="IntroLayout">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

and

```
//res/values-sw600dp/styles.xml
<style name="IntroLayout">
    <item name="android:layout_width">520dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

and use it like

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                style="@style/IntroLayout">
```

which allows me to dynamically set the width and height attributes for different sized devices without having to write any code and you can use match_parent/wrap_content fine. you can use any @dimen that you have defined previously in the style as well if you want.

I use this because the layout for phone and tablet is the same, except i want to fix the width on tablet but fill the parent on phone, so it saves having to have 2 different layouts with basically the same xml

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it doesn't use magic numbers such as -1dp and -2dp and specifies the dimensions explicitly.

Comment: I like the way this one reads, but in certain situations, your app can crash if there is no `layout_height` or `layout_width` explicitly defined within the layout file

Answer (score 10):

For HTC devices use this to achieve match_parent:

```
<dimen name="my_match_parent">-1.0px</dimen>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this using `integers.xml` file

`integers.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="match_parent">-1</integer>
    <integer name="wrap_content">-2</integer>
</resources>
```

Use in `dimens.xml`:

```
<dimen name="main_right_menu_width">@integer/wrap_content</dimen>
```

You might also get `lint` warning, to suppress it use:

```
<dimen name="main_right_menu_width" tools:ignore="ReferenceType">@integer/wrap_content</dimen>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. @dimen/match_parent is a specific length with unit while match_parent is a special flag.

Comment: But I successfully use this technique using wrap_content. Please see my edited post.

Comment: @Rendy, does @dimen/wrap_content behave the same as wrap_content