# Using FILL_PARENT in dimensions.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a  `View` which width must depend on the screen width:

- it must fill the screen on small screens (less than 600dip wide)
- it must have a fixed width (600dip) on bigger screens

I was hoping I could use dimensions stored in XML files:

*mylayout.xml:*

```
 <View
   android:layout_height="100dip"
   android:layout_width="@dimen/myview_width"/>
```

*values-sw600dp/dimensions.xml:*

```
    <dimen name="myview_width">600dip</dimen>
```

*values/dimensions.xml:*

```
    <dimen name="myview_width">FILL_PARENT</dimen> <!-- NOT SUPPORTED -->
```

... but the use of `FILL_PARENT` is not supported in `dimen` elements.

What's the cleanest way to achieve this in XML ?

Comment: fill_parent is deprecated, use match_parent

Comment: `fill_parent` and `match_parent` are the exact same thing, it's really not the issue here.

Comment: You can check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19043952/341998 . In a nutshell, it says that you can use -1 for match_parent and -2 for wrap_content.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use styles for different screens. Like this:

```
 <View
   style="@style/MyStyle"
   android:layout_height="100dip"/>
```

in values-sw600dp/my_style.xml:

```
    <style name="MyStyle">
        <item name="android:layout_width">600dip</item>
    </style>
```

in values/my_style.xml:

```
    <style name="MyStyle">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    </style>
```

With this you can do what you want.

Comment: It is considered bad practice to embed layout properties in style definitions.

Comment: @Moritz Would you mind providing a source for your statement?