# Android Define Match_Parent in Dimens XML

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layoutparams

How can i define the **match_parent** flag in a dimens.xml?

```
<dimen name="width">match_parent</dimen>
```

I tried the methods here [Value equals to match_parent or fill_parent in dimens.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478808/value-equals-to-match-parent-or-fill-parent-in-dimens-xml/37971851#37971851) but none work.

Iam using Android > 27 API.

Comment: You can do that in your styles.xml. I don't think you can put match_parent like you did in dimens.xml. You have to define size in px there.

Comment: @SambitMallick doesnt work

Comment: In styles.xml try <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47321385/8249573 Values can be in dp, px, or sp in dimen.xml.  The link you gave, he/she tried <dimen name="wrap_content">-2dp</dimen> and got the result.

Answer (score 1):

First create attribs.xml:

```
<resources>
    <item name="match_parent" type="dimen">-1</item>
</resources>
```

Second use your dimens:

```
  <dimen name="account_width">@dimen/match_parent</dimen>
```